# Control HTML5 video player loop with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am looking to enable looping of HTML5 video in browsers that do not support the loop tag (ff) with JavaScript. Does anyone know the feasibility of accessing the end of the video play and reverting playback to zero?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can detect if the `loop` property is supported, and set it to `true`.

For browsers that don't support it, you can simply bind the `ended` media event, and start it over:

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById('videoId');
if (typeof myVideo.loop == 'boolean') { // loop supported
  myVideo.loop = true;
} else { // loop property not supported
  myVideo.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
  }, false);
}
//...
myVideo.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop the video on or off through `loop="false"` for stopping auto video repeat play.

```
<iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"
src="http://video/name.mp4" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"  webkitallowfullscreen loop="true" controls="false" mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This `loop="true"` will enable video player loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>Iteration: <span id="iteration"></span></div>

<video id="video-background" autoplay="" muted="" controls>
        <source src="https://res.sdfdsf.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

var iterations = 1;

    document.getElementById('iteration').innerText = iterations;

        var myVideo = document.getElementById('video-background');
    myVideo.addEventListener('ended', function () {    
                alert('end');
        if (iterations < 2) {
            this.currentTime = 0;
            this.play();
            iterations ++;          
            document.getElementById('iteration').innerText = iterations;
        }   

    }, false);


   // Please note that loop attribute should not be there in video element in order for the 'ended' event to work in ie and firefox
```